# Creating persistent unique links

Tags: angular

I'm building an app that allows users to search and create a list of their favourite music albums. So far the users can create the list.

But now I need to be able to create a new and unique link for each list created so that users can share it on social media. Can anybody tell me how to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you are already done with the part of creating a new list, the rest is pretty straightforward.

I am assuming you store these lists in a database somewhere. What you need now is create separate routes for each list with its unique identifier. This unique identifier can be something generated by you ( like say alphanumeric string ) or something as simple as the id of this list in your DB.

Once that is done, you can create a component ( say ListItemComponent )
and then use it in your router modules routes.

```
{ path: 'list/:id', component: ListItemComponent },
```

Inside your component's OnInit, you can get this ID,

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
 var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
}
```

You can use this ID to fetch the list from your backend.

Also, since you want social media sharing, if you want to set meta tags (title, description etc.) for these routes when sharing on fb etc, I sugges you look into Server side rendering.

**Based on what you wanted in the comments.**

https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/

Refer this API. You can make calls to this API to create a gist whenever the user wants to share their list. You will get the URL to that gist as part of the response. It is very clearly explained in the documentation.

```
POST /gists
```

Say the URL of this new gist is -

https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d

Now, what you could do is use this ID ('aa5a315d61ae9438b18d') in your website as well. 
That is, say yoursite.com/lists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d 
From the method above, fetch the ID, use it to get the gist from github and you are done!

```
GET /gists/:id
```

This should work. Not just with github gists but with any such thing that provides an API. 
Hoping this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I haven't stored the lists in a db yet but I assume that's one way of doing it. Alternatively, I've heard that it can alternatively done via Github gists... is that something you might have any idea about?

Comment: A gist is just used for a small piece of content (generally unconnected to other code), like for discussing and giving examples which is relevant to you here I guess. I suppose you could use their API to create an gist (even anonymous ones are allowed) and then share that link, maybe? But then, that would mean the lists are not part of your website anymore.

Comment: Ah! Wait, I think there is a workaround for that as well in case you want github gists. Will edit the answer with that.

Comment: Forgot to add this in the answer, but you can just send any user information like name etc. as part of the gist itself

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I am storing each list as a gist in JSON format. Then when I want to serve each list, I simply make a request to a gist (using the gist id), get the json data and populate the list page (mysite.com/list/gistID) in my site. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The Github gists API returns everything in JSON format. If this solution solves your problem, do upvote and accept my answer! :D